# Mongodb monitoring using mikoomi plugin of zabbix is not rendering any data

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, zabbix

I'm using [`mikoomi` plugin](https://code.google.com/p/mikoomi/wiki/03) to monitor `mongodb`, in that there is shell script which is calling `php` script and returning 0 to `zabbix` and `parallely` writing a data file and log file in `/tmp/` directory.

Now my question : How is `zabbix` reading that data/log file and how are keys fetching information from that file? I need to debug this because `zabbix` is not rendering any data.
How do I set this up correctly?

Format of data file is as follows:

```
<Mongo Hostname> mem_virtual 39484
<Mongo Hostname> connections_current 34
<Mongo Hostname> mem_resident 1018
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Have suggested the move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

Mikoomi script is using [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manpages/zabbix_sender) utility to notify zabbix server about the data collected.

```
exec("zabbix_sender -vv -z 127.0.0.1 -i $data_file_name 2>&1", $log_file_data) ;
```

Zabbix server will read the key values from data file and update the db.

Which OS are you using? Check for `selinux` policy related errors. If `selinux` policies are enabled in your server, disable and check whether data file is getting updated.

For checking `selinux` policy enable/disable, run below command

```
getenforce
```

If the output is `Enforcing` then `selinux` policies are enabled. Disable using following command.

```
setenforce 0
```

And again run `getenforce` to check whether the output is `Permissive`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you configured a cron job to run the script for every MongoDB host.

something along the lines of:

```
* * * * * /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/mikoomi-mongodb-plugin.sh -h [ip address] -p 27017 -z [hostname]
```

the hostname has to be as it's configured in Zabbix for the target MongoDB server